# How update using three tables JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I did make it work using old style notation.

**[DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=fb92c6aa5dcbcefa6d8fb98c6ceb9604)**

```
UPDATE
    route_sources rs
SET
    has_route = false
FROM avl a1, avl a2 
WHERE rs.avl_id_begin = a1.avl_id
  AND rs.avl_id_end = a2.avl_id 
  AND 0 IN (a1.azimuth, a2.azimuth)
```

But wondering if can be write using explicit join sintaxis:

```
UPDATE
    route_sources rs
SET
    has_route = false
FROM avl a1
JOIN avl a2 
  ON rs.avl_id_end = a2.avl_id   <= this doesnt work
WHERE rs.avl_id_begin = a1.avl_id
  AND 0 IN (a1.azimuth, a2.azimuth)
```

> ERROR:  referencia a la entrada de la cláusula FROM para la tabla «rs» no válida
>   LINE 10:   ON rs.avl_id_end = a2.avl_id
>                 ^
>   HINT:  Hay una entrada para la tabla «rs», pero no puede ser referenciada desde esta parte de la consulta.

Translate to something like.

Reference to `rs` in the `FROM` clausule isnt valid. HINT: There is one entry to `rs`, but cant be reference on this part of the query.

Also try using the full name instead of the alias but didn't work neither.

Comment: Please prepare sample data using http://www.rextester.com. How about doing join (3 tables) in cte and then update using target table and cte?

Comment: @lad2025 Rexter isnt working for me, I add dbFiddle instead

Comment: `WITH cte AS (
    SELECT rs.route_source_id
    FROM route_sources rs
    JOIN avl a1
      ON rs.avl_id_begin = a1.avl_id
    JOIN avl a2 
      ON rs.avl_id_end = a2.avl_id
    WHERE 0 IN (a1.azimuth, a2.azimuth)
)
UPDATE  route_sources rt
SET has_route = false
FROM cte c
WHERE c.route_source_id = rt.route_source_id`

Comment: Or using subquery: `UPDATE route_sources rt 
SET has_route = false 
FROM (SELECT rs.route_source_id 
    FROM route_sources rs 
    JOIN avl a1 ON rs.avl_id_begin = a1.avl_id 
    JOIN avl a2 ON rs.avl_id_end = a2.avl_id 
    WHERE 0 IN (a1.azimuth, a2.azimuth)) s
WHERE s.route_source_id  = rt.route_source_id`

Comment: @lad2025  Both seem to work too.  But looks like old style version is easier to read.

Comment: In my opinion old style is harder, I like cte because I can see what is selected, then update is just execution (update/delete/...). In SQL Server I can just write `WITH cte ... UPDATE cte SET ...` But I believe it is not possible in PostgreSQL so I have to join once again.

Comment: SQL Server version: http://rextester.com/GMX78251 this kind of syntax is very clear. `WITH cte AS 
( 
 SELECT rs.route_source_id, has_route
 FROM route_sources rs 
 JOIN avl a1 ON rs.avl_id_begin = a1.avl_id 
 JOIN avl a2 ON rs.avl_id_end = a2.avl_id 
 WHERE 0 IN (a1.azimuth, a2.azimuth)
)
 UPDATE cte
 SET has_route = 0`

Comment: @lad2025 Yes, postgresql update sintaxis is just weird. :(

Comment: BTW Thanks for dbFiddle, nice webpage :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use subquery/cte to select rows and then join to target table:

```
WITH cte AS ( 
  SELECT rs.route_source_id 
  FROM route_sources rs 
  JOIN avl a1 ON rs.avl_id_begin = a1.avl_id 
  JOIN avl a2 ON rs.avl_id_end = a2.avl_id 
  WHERE 0 IN (a1.azimuth, a2.azimuth)
) 
UPDATE route_sources rt 
SET has_route = false 
FROM cte c 
WHERE c.route_source_id = rt.route_source_id;
```

or:

```
UPDATE route_sources rt 
SET has_route = false 
FROM (SELECT rs.route_source_id 
      FROM route_sources rs 
      JOIN avl a1 ON rs.avl_id_begin = a1.avl_id 
      JOIN avl a2 ON rs.avl_id_end = a2.avl_id 
      WHERE 0 IN (a1.azimuth, a2.azimuth)) s 
WHERE s.route_source_id = rt.route_source_id;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/QBERL27668)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The point is that a1 and a2 are not associated (only via rs)
This mightbe simpler(and faster). It wil also avoid multiple updates to the same row.

---

```
UPDATE route_sources rs
SET has_route = false
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT* FROM avl a1 
        WHERE a1.avl_id= rs.avl_id_begin 
        AND a1.azimuth =0
        )
OR EXISTS (SELECT* FROM avl a2 
        WHERE a2.avl_id = rs.avl_id_end
        AND a2.azimuth= 0
        );
```

Comment: Maybe wasn't clear on my description but the idea is one `avl` can be the beginning or the end of the a route and both are in the `avl` table. But I will try this.

Comment: My conclusion was: you either want avl_id_begin or avl_id_end to refer to an avl -record with azimuth=0. (or both)

Comment: Yes I realize when gps hasn't a satellite fix the azimuth is 0 by default, so most of the routes with azimuth  0 are wrong and those are invalid routes. Right now loading some data to test performance.

Comment: I do not know if you want *both* waypoints to exist.(I think they should, since the JOIN is probably an FK->PK join)